# Viewing 2D subsurface seismic data (raster file) in QGIS using 2threejs 3d plugin

Tags: geology, qgis2threejs

I am an exploration geologist and trying to figure out if there is a way to view SUBSURFACE data using the QGIS 2threejs plugin? I have a seismic raster which I would like to view in 3D, with vectorized surface geology draped over. This is the kind of thing you would complete in leapfrog, but I would love to hear if anyone knows how to do this in QGIS!

Answer (score 1):

There is possibility to show images on vertical planes in QGIS. I prepared geological block diagram based on images of geological cross sections. See my web page https://arcsaga.wordpress.com and link to 3d model Geology of Carter Lake Reservoir Area. This model was performed using QGIS and threejs editor.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge you cannot view vertical raster cross-section in QGIS but I wish you could.  One option is to convert the raster cells to a point layer and then rotate them to their correct 3D position.  Not great but it is an easy option.